# Cakephp subquery in paginate

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I have an existing cakephp (version 2) controller index function doing this:

```
$options = ['Person.name LIKE' => $term];
$this->set('people', $this->Paginator->paginate($options));
```

resulting in a paginated table in the view.

My Person model references a child model of Appointment, where one person has many appointments like so:

```
public $hasMany = [
    'Appointment' => [
        'className' => 'Appointment',
        'foreignKey' => 'person_id',
        'dependent' => false
    ]
]
```

I now need to add a Person's Oldest Appointment Date column to my table, i.e. if working with raw SQL I might do this:

```
select 
    Person.id,
    Person.name,
    (select 
        min(Appointment.Date) from Appointment
        where Appointment.person_id = Person.id
    ) as OldestAppointmentDate
from Person
where Person.name like 'foo%'
```

How can I modify the paginate() parameters so that this new field is included in the results and is sortable by paginate in the usual way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most simple way would probably be to use a virtual field, which you can then include in the paginators `fields` option, something like:

```
// in Model/Person.php

public $virtualFields = array(
    'OldestAppointmentDate' => '
        select
            min(Appointment.Date)
        from
            Appointment
        where
            Appointment.person_id = Person.id
    ';
);
```

```
// in your controller action

$this->Paginator->settings['fields'] = array(
    'Person.id',
    'Person.name'
    'Person.OldestAppointmentDate'
);

// ...
```

That will include the subquery and create the required aliases accordingly, and things get stitched together automatically so that the results look like as if `OldestAppointmentDate` is an actual field of `Person`, and you can refer to it in the paginator helper like any other field, ie:

```
$this->Paginator->sort('Person.OldestAppointmentDate');
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Models > Virtual fields](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Core Libraries > Components > Pagination > Query Setup](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#query-setup)**

Comment: That worked well, thanks. As a note to self and for the benefit of any others, in my case I found I had to set up `virtualFields` in the model's constructor instead, as detailed here: https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#virtual-fields-and-model-aliases